# Connection between micro controller and external flash

Tags: microcontroller, flash-memory

I am using an stm32f2xx-series controller in my project. I want to know whether an external flash is connected to the micro-controller or not without doing any read/write operations to the external flash. Is that possible?

If yes, please explain the means to do so.

If it matters, communication between the controller and the external flash is SPI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sentence "I want to know whether an external flash is connected to the micro-controller or not without doing any read/write operations to the external flash." doesn't make any sense. Do you wish to know if an external flash is connected to a microcontroller, or do you want to know if doing so causes read/writes, or do you want to know if you can have it connected even though you don't plan to use it?

Comment: Anyway this question is far too broad and also about electronics, not programming.

Comment: Without an idea what you want to do in C, there is no point in adding any language tags. It's about hardware stuff.

Comment: not only has nothing to do with C has nothing to do with microcontrollers either, explain how you would detect a spi (i2c, etc) flash without attempting to talk to it?  How is this flash connected do you have a plug in module to your board?  then just put a presence detect on that or build one into the board design if this is about some boards have one some dont.

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of any way your firmware can detect the presence of an SPI device without talking to it.  Reading a status or device identification register is how you typically probe for it.